# How to set form submission redirection on different page (5 second interval) using jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery

I like to setup 5 second interval after form submission, then redirect to different page.

here is html code:

```
<button type="button" id="submit">Submit</button>
```

Right now,I'm using this jquery for redirect onclick 5 second interval.

```
$('#submit').click(function(){
  setTimeout(function(){
       window.location.href='index.php';
  },5000);
});
```

I changed `.click(function()` to `.submit(function()` but didn't worked.

is there have any way to set 5 second interval after submitting form?

Thank you.

Comment: If you are submitting your form, then at server end you can redirect to respective page. Why you need to redirect at client side ?

Comment: are you sending the form to the same page and you want to have a five seconds delay before submitting?

Comment: Okay, Thanks for the suggestion. I like to redirect on different page without touching server side.

Answer (score 1):

Use `preventDefault()` to stop form submission and execute your code

```
$('#submit').on('click', function(e){
  e.preventDefault();
  setTimeout(function(){
    window.location.href='index.php';
  },5000);
});
```